# How to install jupyter notebook without Anaconda?In windows 7

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am making a react- native application.I am using firebase for authentication.I ran this `npm install firebase` it was installed successfully and I was added in package.json file too but when I write this `import * as firebase from 'firebase'`.It gives me this : can't resolve firebase.Firebase version : latest v9.Please help me.

Comment: cant find any relevance in the question title and description

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Path where Jupyter Notebook is installed.
Mostly it should be in

```
C:\Users\welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

From there run **jupyter-notebook.exe** file. It will be opened in browser.

Note : For my case it is welcome , for your case it can be your username.

```
C:\Users\atharva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```

Basically you have to choose your path where python is installed.

This Answer is taken from [How to install jupyter notebook without anaconda](https://www.hindicodingcommunity.com/2021/07/how-to-install-jupyter-notebook-without-anaconda.html)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you need to set the respective required PATH as a system variable and/or environment variable.[image]

Comment: I appreciate your efforts towards learning python. however, if you want to take it to the next level you may consider some blogs eg. [link] (https://cppsecrets.com/users/7927971001051161051071111161041051219710855484864103109971051084699111109/Python-K-means-Music-Genre-Classification.php ) and you may also consider joining AWS coding events: bug buster [link]( https://aws.amazon.com/bugbust/ )

Answer (score 1):

1. While installing python make sure to check these points.
   a. pip setting
   [image: pip setting]

   b. add to Environment variable
   [image: add to Environment variable]
2. Make sure these python variables is present in Environment Variables settings.
   [image]
3. Open command-prompt and type: "pip install jupyter" and it looks like this..
   [image: pip installing jupyter]
4. After jupyter installation done. Type in command prompt: "jupyter notebook"
   after few seconds jupyter server start and show this info in command prompt and open notebook in you browser as this..
   [image: starting jupyter notebook]

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling python. While installation, remember to  click “add python to path” option.

Open **Command Prompt (cmd)** and type:

```
python -m pip install -upgrade pip 
#or, for python 2 users
python3 -m pip install -upgrade pip
```

After upgrading pip, write this -

```
python -m pip install jupyter
```

To open Jupyter notebook, write `jupyter notebook` in the cmd

**Then, the Jupyter Notebook is opened in the browser**

**for more info** - [installing jupyter without anaconda](https://itguykelly.wordpress.com/2018/09/30/install-jupyter-notebook-without-anaconda/)

Comment: Thanks bruh!I have added it to path already